# Custom message for python type hint error

Tags: python

Example:

```
MyType = List[str]
x: MyType = 'ciao'
```

static analyser (PyCharm) say: `Expected type 'List[str]', got 'str' instead`

I want to customize this hint, example: `Variables of type MyType are lists of strings`. There's a standard way, possibly working on multiple editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in PyCharm, as the static analyser is hard coded with messages.

although the answer by Sayandip Dutta is your best bet

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`typing.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype). The documentation says:

> The static type checker will treat the new type as if it were a subclass of the original type.

For example:

```
from typing import List, NewType

MyType = NewType('MyType', List[str])
x: MyType = 'ciao'
```

running `mypy`:

```
mypy check.py
check.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "MyType")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

You could also use [`TypeAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias)

```
from typing import List, TypeAlias

MyType: TypeAlias = List[str]
x: MyType = 'ciao'
# ^ Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "MyType")
```

Comment: But is it possible to customize the static analyzer message?